# Javascript - touchstart and touchend locations

Tags: javascript, html, touch

I would like to get the touchstart and touchend locations if element "#menu" is touched.

I wrote this code, but the event doesn't seem to trigger at all:

```
        var lastLoc = 0;

        $(document).on('touchstart', '#menu', function(e) {
            lastLoc = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
        });

        $(document).on('touchend', '#menu', function(e) {
            var newLoc = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
            alert("lastLoc = "+lastLoc+", newLoc = "+newLoc);
        });
```

As far as I know this should work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `touchend` event should, logically, have zero `touch` points, only `changedTouches`.

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/703614ee/)

```
function startHandler (e) {
    window.console.log('Start:', e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX);
}

function endHandler (e) {
    window.console.log('End:', e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageX);
}



$(document).on('touchstart', '#menu', startHandler);
$(document).on('touchend', '#menu', endHandler);
```

See also: [Simulating touchstart and touchend events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406783/simulating-touchstart-and-touchend-events) if you are having trouble testing touch events.

Answer (score 0):

You need to test the touch event on a touchable surface such as a smartphone or a tablet.
In Google Chrome there is a way to simulate this function.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for your trouble, I ended up using jquery mobile's "swipeleft"
Thanks anyway :)